# NSCFCalendar dateFromComponents: components cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar

After executing the following code

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *expiryDateComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitEra|NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate:aDate];
```

you get the following non-crashing exception

```
*** -[__NSCFCalendar dateFromComponents:]: components cannot be nil
Future exception.
A few of these errors are going to be reported with this complaint, then further violations will simply be ignored.
```

Comment: Not really a question, more of a "Hey look what I found".

Comment: @zaph Oh, isn't that one of the use cases of SO? There is a reason why they have a feature called "Answer your own question – share your knowledge" when asking a new "question". ;)

Comment: Yes and no. Should we all make a posts every time we discover something, trivial or not? Thousands developers times several ties a week? In this case a non-obvious error message? And the solution, don't pass nil for a the date; of course you don't pass nil if you want the components of the date.

Comment: @zaph "Yes and no"? Hah, tell that to SO people. Next time someone will lose an hour or two with a trivial thing like this one, this answer will make a lot of sense for him. Oh, I'm sorry, I forgot that you are one of those devs who never stumbles upon a trivial thing. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** make sure the `fromDate` parameter is **not nil**.

*Explanation*:

`NSCalendar` doesn't know how to handle the situation when you give it a nil `NSDate`. The API is giving you a warning instead of throwing a crashing exception. Beware that this behaviour can change and may cause a crash in the future due to API changes.